# Print comma separated tokens when they have been looked up in another node

Tags: xslt

This example show a pretty standard way to use for-each to loop through the data and print each value separated by a comma. The first item is not preceded by a comma by use of the `position()` function.

INPUT:

```
<file><data>
    <item>Anton</item>
    <item>Bruce</item>
    <item>Chris</item>
</data></file>
```

TRANSFORMATION:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/file/data" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/file/data">
    <xsl:for-each select="item">
        <xsl:if test="position()&gt;1">
            <xsl:value-of select="', '" />
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

RESULT:

```
Anton, Bruce, Chris
```

The next example prints names like in the previous example, but this time the names were looked up in a separate node.

INPUT:

```
<file>
    <data>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>4</item>
        <item>6</item>
    </data>

    <names>
        <person><id>1</id><name>Anton</name></person>
        <person><id>2</id><name>Bruce</name></person>
        <person><id>3</id><name>Chris</name></person>
        <person><id>4</id><name>Dirk</name></person>
        <person><id>5</id><name>Erik</name></person>
        <person><id>6</id><name>Fred</name></person>
    </names>
</file>
```

TRANSFORMATION:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/file/data" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/file/data">
    <xsl:for-each select="item">
        <xsl:call-template name="getNames">
            <xsl:with-param name="soughtid">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="getNames">
    <xsl:param name="soughtid" />

    <xsl:for-each select="/file/names/person">
        <xsl:variable name="currentid">
            <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:if test="$currentid=$soughtid">
            <xsl:if test="position()&gt;1">         <!-- problematic -->
                <xsl:value-of select="', '"/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

RESULT:

```
, Bruce, Dirk, Fred
```

This time the result starts with a comma. That makes sense because now position() refers to the iterator over the `<names>` node. The first item to print is the second `<person>` in the `<names>` node.

How can I fix this code so that the result never starts with a comma? I'm using XSLT v1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make sure you process only the elements that interest you by moving the comparison into a predicate e.g. `<xsl:for-each select="/file/names/person[id = $soughtid]">`.

I would restructure the whole code to use a key:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:key name="pers-by-id" match="names/person" use="id"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('pers-by-id', file/data/item)/name"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="name">
      <xsl:if test="position() > 1">, </xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ej9EGc4

Comment: Thanks. Your solution also seems to get rid of the O(n²) complexity that mine suffers.