# Lookup items in different nodes

Tags: xslt

This is a follow up on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54959068/print-comma-separated-tokens-when-they-have-been-looked-up-in-another-node).

I have the following input XML

```
<file>
    <data>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>4</item>
        <item>6</item>
        <item>7</item>
    </data>

    <names>
        <person><id>1</id><name>Anton</name></person>
        <person><id>2</id><name>Bruce</name></person>
        <person><id>3</id><name>Chris</name></person>
        <person><id>4</id><name>Dirk</name></person>
        <person><id>5</id><name>Erik</name></person>
        <person><id>6</id><name>Fred</name></person>
    </names>

    <morenames>
        <person><id>6</id><name>Ferdinand</name></person>
        <person><id>7</id><name>George</name></person>
    </morenames>
</file>
```

This XSLT will show `Bruce, Dirk, Fred`

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:key name="pers-by-id" match="names/person" use="id"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('pers-by-id', file/data/item)/name"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="name">
      <xsl:if test="position() > 1">, </xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Does anyone know how I could modify this XSLT so that it will show `Bruce, Dirk, Fred, George`?
Note that:

- items should be looked up in `<names>` first
- only if not found in `<names>` an attempt should be made to find the item in `<morenames>`
- Ferdinand should never show because its `<id>` also appears in `<names>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion of the adaption of the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54959155/252228 would be

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:key name="pers-by-id" match="names/person" use="id"/>
  <xsl:key name="other-pers-by-id" match="morenames/person" use="id"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates 
        select="key('pers-by-id', file/data/item)/name | 
                key('other-pers-by-id', file/data/item[not(key('pers-by-id', .))])/name"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="name">
      <xsl:if test="position() > 1">, </xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ej9EGc4/2

Answer (score 1):

How about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0 "
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:key name="name-by-id" match="names/person" use="id"/>
<xsl:key name="alt-name-by-id" match="morenames/person" use="id"/>

<xsl:template match="/file">
    <xsl:for-each select="data/item">
        <xsl:variable name="name" select="key('name-by-id', .)" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$name">
                <xsl:value-of select="$name/name"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="key('alt-name-by-id', .)/name"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">, </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

If `names` always comes before `morenames` in the input XML, you could shorten this to:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0 "
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:key name="name-by-id" match="person" use="id"/>

<xsl:template match="/file">
    <xsl:for-each select="data/item">
        <xsl:value-of select="key('name-by-id', .)[1]/name"/>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">, </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```